# PySpark creating CSV does not work, _SUCCESS file only

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

This might be a stupid question, but I've just started to learn spark and now I'm facing my first problem, that I cannot solve with books and google...

I'm working with Zeppelin and trying to do some analysis with a serverlog.

My df looks like:

[image]

Now I want to save it as a CSV with following code:

```
df_reduced.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("/home/hduser/tmp")
```

And I'm getting always a new _SUCCESS file, but no CSV:

[image]

What am I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your spark running using yarn/hdfs?

Comment: Yes. But I want to save this file locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it with

```
df_pd = df_reduced.toPandas()
df_pd.to_csv("test.csv")
```

But this feels a bit like a workaround.

Would be happy for any suggestion how I could solve it without Pandas.

Comment: What a brilliant idea!